# Multiprocessing Class in Subprocess

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, subprocess

I want to use python's multiprocessing module in a class, which itself uses subprocesses to not block the main call.

The minimal example looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp


class mpo():

def __init__(self):
    cpu = mp.cpu_count()
    self.Pool = mp.Pool(processes = 2)
    self.alive = True
    self.p = mp.Process(target = self.sub,args=())

def worker():
    print 'Alive'

def sub(self):
    print self.alive

    for i in range(2):
        print i
        self.Pool.apply_async(self.worker, args=())
    print 'done'
    self.Pool.close()
#   self.Pool.join()
```

I commented the last line out, as it raises an assertion Error (can only join a child process). 
When I do:

```
m =mpo()
m.p.start()
```

The output is

```
True
0
1
done
```

My main question is, why the print statement in the worker thread never is reached?

**Update:**

The updated code looks like this.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


class mpo():

    def __init__(self):
        cpu = mp.cpu_count()
        self.alive = True
        self.p = mp.Process(target = self.sub,args=())
        self.result=[]

    def worker(self):
        self.result.append(1)
        print 'Alive'

    def sub(self):
        print self.alive
        Pool = mp.Pool(processes = 2)
        for i in range(2):
            print i
            Pool.apply_async(self.worker, args=())
        print 'done'
        Pool.close()
        Pool.join()
```

The pool now doesn't have to be inherited as it is created in the subprocess. Instead of the print statement the result is appended to the calling object and the pool is properly joined. Nevertheless, there is no result showing up.

Comment: This example doesn't run at all for me.  I am getting a `NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled`  from the `Process.start()`.  Obviously it doesn't like sending the `Pool` to the `Process`

Comment: Moving the pool into the sub function doesn't change that behaviour.

Comment: there are several issues (1) inheriting pool in a child process (2) calling `.join()` (3) inheriting stdout in worker processes. You could resolve these issues one by one but it looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Do you have ideas for resolving these issues? Actually, I am having the original problem resolved by simple  (manual) sub-processing. I just really want to understand what's wrong with my posted code as I want to understand the co-existence of classes, pools and subprocesses.

Comment: The easiest way to get your code working is to use a function which is not part of your class. In your case, 2 processes could start writing on the same variable self.result at the same time which is not allowed. Moreover you seem to rather need map_async not apply_async because you want to execute the same function several times. Check out the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) and always keep the function and variables that you are using seperate. One last thing: do not use the print statement in async. processes.

Comment: Following up on user1901493's comment, a bound method is not pickleable so it can't be passed through multiprocessing, so it's best to use an unbound function. Also instead of putting results in a list, use a multiprocessing.Queue. You'll run into async problems like race conditions otherwise.  In your case it might be easier to just return a value from the worker function and call .get() on it.

Comment: Your second code example solves the 1st and 2nd issues but introduces another one with trying to modify copies of  a  list in different processes. You could use a callback (look at apply_async()` docs), to pass the result from the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I think this may correspond to a simple example of what you are looking for:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(arg):
    #print 'Alive'+str(arg)
    return "Alive and finished {0}".format(arg)

class mpo():
    def __init__(self):
        cpu = mp.cpu_count()
        self.alive = True
        self.pool = mp.Pool(processes = 2)
    def sub(self,arguments):
        self.results=self.pool.map_async(worker, arguments)
        return self.results

if __name__=="__main__":
    s=mpo()
    s.sub(range(10))
    print s.results.get()
```

Additionally you can call

```
self.results.ready()
```

to find out whether the processes have finished their work. You do not have to put this inside of another process because the map_async call does not block the rest of your program.

**EDIT:**
Concerning your comment, I do not really see the value of putting the calculation in a separate process, because the function is already running in separate processes (in the pool). You only add complexity by nesting it in another subprocess, but it is possible:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def worker(arg):
    #print 'Alive'+str(arg)
    return "Alive and finished {0}".format(arg)
class mpo():
    def __init__(self):
        cpu = mp.cpu_count()
        self.alive = True
        self.pool = mp.Pool(processes = 2)
    def sub(self,arguments):
        self.results=self.pool.map_async(worker, arguments)
        return self.results
def run_calculation(q):
    s=mpo()
    results=s.sub(range(10))
    q.put(results.get())

queue=mp.Queue()
proc=mp.Process(target=run_calculation,args=(queue,))
proc.start()
proc.join()
queue.get()
```

Comment: I explicitly want my multiprocessing to be in a subprocess because of the broader structure of my program. Nevertheless this answer is beautiful and will help me a lot.